# Android Application, Client-Server communication

Tags: android, client-server, communication

HeyHo,

which opportunities do I have to implement a client-server architecture for an android application. I simply want to transmit results from my database server to my application. I was researching on the internet and found different solutions but I ain't sure which one fits the best and is the simplest one:
- XML-RPC
- RESTlet
- REST + JSON

Maybe there is even a more simple way to do this and I haven't considered it yet.

Thanks for your helpful answers in advance

Cheers
Ei.Schinken

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Rest+JSon is best option and simple to do and there are lot of references available for help.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on yout server architecture, for example We have here a Mysql database with PHPmyadmin, so I'm using Json with PHP, and works fine for me.